# nodejs & express 4, res.json returns "Content-Type: text/plain"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make my application return "application/json" as the content type whenever the response is a json of course.

I have tried:

```
res.json(jsonContent);

response header has "Content-Type → text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

and

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/json');
res.send(jsonContent); 

response header has "Content-Type → text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

and

```
res.set('content-type', 'text/json');
res.send(jsonContent); 

response header has "Content-Type → text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

and all of the above at the same time. But my app always server responses as text/plain and never application/json. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your setup (and applied middleware), if the client's request was not made with Accept: application/json, then the response's content type might be getting set to just text/plain.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Do you know which middleware makes this or there are multiple that could make the same thing?

Comment: I would check bodyParser.json() - check out the source for it, it's very small and it should give you a pretty good idea!

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.type) explains:

```
res.type('json');               // => 'application/json'
res.type('application/json');   // => 'application/json'
```

Sets the Content-Type HTTP header to the specified type.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your routing is not doing what you think so you are hitting a different route entirely than you think you are. Probably you are hitting the default 404 not found handler route. Instead of posting the 1 line you think is wrong, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can help you find the problem.